# Return the user to their original position on a page when they close navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with manipulating foundations off-canvas navigation to get it to do what I want and it's been causing quite a few issues. One main one I've noticed is that when I stick the header to the top of the page so it scrolls with me as I go down pages, when you open it it opens at the top of the page. So for that I added a .click(function) to get the page to scroll back to the top which can be found here:

**jQuery:**

```
  jQuery('section.left-small a.menu-icon').click(function() {
      var screenTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
      jQuery('#content').css('top', screenTop);
        //console.log(screenTop); 
      jQuery('body').scrollTop(0);
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
 <nav class="tab-bar">
    <section class="left-small">
        <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>  
    </section>
    <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
        <h1 class="title uppercase"><a href="/">Island Company</a></h1>
        <a href="/checkout/suitcase.html">
            <img src="/media/island/suitcase.png" />
            <span class="suitcase-item-count">(<?= $quote->getItemCount(); ?>)</span>&nbsp;
        </a> 
    </section>
 </nav>
```

So my question is how do I use the variable "screenTop" to get the page to return to it's stored original position within the body of the page when the user CLOSES the "a.left-off-canvas-toggle" menu?

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CMbBC/18/

Comment: it's nice to paste your code on fiddle

Comment: Have you tried to get the "div" (or any else container) offset top, store that data into a variable and use it to scroll?

Comment: Man Programmer, I added a fiddle.

Maurizio, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that

Comment: set your off canvas to be fixed so page doesn't need to scroll

Comment: Charlietfl, that doesn't work because the off-canvas always opens up at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this slution is somewhat close to your answer.

> JQuery

```
$("#check").click(function() {
  if ($("#menu").is(":hidden")) {
     $(document).scrollTop(lastPos);
  } else {
     // do that
  }
});
var lastPos=0;
$("#getInfo").click(function(){
   $("#menu").toggle();
    lastPos=$(document).scrollTop();
});
```

In demo first click on `getInfo` then click `check`
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5d9ttjmh/)

> Update 1:

```
$( document).scroll(function() {
    //store current scroll pos  
    //lastPos=$(document).scrollTop();
});
var lastPos=0;
$("#getInfo").click(function(){
    //store scroll pos befor toggle
    lastPos=$(document).scrollTop();    
    $( "#menu" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
        if ($("#menu").is(":hidden")) {
           $(document).scrollTop(lastPos);
        } else {
           // do that
        }
    });    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fe0tyqpx/)

Comment: Only problem with this is I only have one button that I can click. I don't have two different buttons that I can click on, like this example

Answer (score 0):

if i'm right to understand your question you want to scroll original position try this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var screenTop=jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    //sending page to the top when menu opens up
    jQuery('.left-small a.menu-icon').click(function() {

        //need to be able to send page back to original position before clicking on menu button
        //jQuery('#content').css('top', screenTop);

        console.log(screenTop); 

        temp = jQuery(document).scrollTop(); 

        jQuery('body').scrollTop(screenTop);
        screenTop = temp;

        //when top menu closes, return page to previous location
        //previous location is stored in var screenTop
        //jQuery('body').animate(screenTop);
        //if ('a.menu-icon')
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CMbBC/21/)

Comment: This works the way I want it to, except it's flipped. When I close the menu, I want the page to return to the position it was at when I opened the menu. Right now when I scroll down and open the navigation, it goes back up to the top. And then when I close it, it stays at the top. But then when I open and close it again, it returns to the position it was at when I first opened the navigation